# MVVMCross TextChanged Event

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, monotouch.dialog

I'am using XAMARIN with MVVMCross Framework.I was wondering if there is an easy way to perform TextChanged binding  in an android editText control between view and viewmodel and vice versa. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - TextChanged is used in almost all the N+1 video tutorials

e.g.:

- N=0 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/
- with Android binding source at https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-00-FirstDemo/FirstDemo.Droid/Resources/Layout/FirstView.axml

An example two-way EditText binding is:

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="40dp"
  local:MvxBind="Text FirstName"
  />
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply. What I actually want to do is when I type in the TextEdit an ICommand event should be fired with the new text value.

Comment: Ask this as a new question, because there is a lot to say about this.

Comment: Well, "TextChanged" was in the title.